# Submit function executing multiple times when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a file upload form where I am checking the file size through javascript before finally submitting the form. The form is working fine and when I try to upload a file more than the mentioned size then it shows the correct alert at the first time. But if I again click on upload without selecting another file I get the same alert twice. If I again repeat the process I get the alert 3 times. Below is the code

```
<script>    
var flag=0;
$('#filename').bind('change', function() { 
var filesiz =  this.files[0].size;
if (filesiz >10485760)
{flag=1;}
else 
{flag=0;}
});

function upfunc(){
  $('#smalldata').hide();
  $('#invalidfile').hide();
  $('#invalidfile9').hide();
  if($( "#UserComments" ).hasClass( "textAreaField valid" ) && $( "#filename" ).hasClass( "valid" )){
  $('#loading_image').show(); // show animation
  $( "#uploadsfrm" ).submit(function() {
  if(flag==1)
  {alert ('File size cannot exceed 10 MB.');
  $('#loading_image').hide();
  return false;
  //event.preventDefault();
  }
  else
  return true;
  });
  }
 }
</script>
```

I think the error may be because I am using bind. Any help would be really appreciated.Thank you

Comment: If you're not selecting another file, the same file is still selected, so why would you expect a different result ?

Comment: But I am not able to understand as to why the second time I am getting the alert two times and then the third time the alert increases to three. Also how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: That's because you placed the event handler inside a function, and everytime upfunc() runs, a new event handler is added, and another alert pops up, making two, then three etc.

Comment: So can you please guide me in the right direction as I am not that proficient.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea where you are calling upfunc() ?

Comment: I am calling upfunc onclick of upload button

Comment: Every thime you click that upload button you're running the code that adds an event handler on submit of the form, and event handlers are automatically removed, more are just added, and the alert will fire for every event handler.

Comment: Means I need to remove event handlers after my work is done. That is I need to use unbind or something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a multi event calling in here. 
Every time you call upfunc() you attach a Submit event.
you might consider either declaring Submit event once or use `$( "#uploadsfrm" ).unbind('submit')` before the
 `$( "#uploadsfrm" ).submit(function()....`

so in fact, first call you will have 1 event listener, 2nd call you will attach another event, which now sums up to 2..there until infinite.
e.preventProgration or StopDefault wont help because its the same object and therefor it wont stop the calling of the events.
Even if it will help, it is just a piece of bad code :(

Comment: Thanks. Unbind function did the trick. Now its working absolutely fine.